# MIN IF for sub ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I had asked this question for MAX IF for sub ranges before. how to find the maximum value (col A) for different items into a range (col B in this case) written on the C col

```
|    A    |    B    |    C    |
|   10    |   cat   |         |
|   15    |   cat   |         |
|    5    |   dog   |         |
|    4    |   dog   |         |
|   11    |   dog   |         |
|    6    |  fish   |         |
|   10    |  fish   |         |
```

ppl answered me `=MAX(INDEX(("$B$1:$B$7=B1)*$A$1:$A$7,0))` which works fine, but when i tried to use it for the minimum values, I mean `=MIN(INDEX(("$B$1:$B$7=B1)*$A$1:$A$7,0))` i got zero for the whole C col.

what could i do wrong?

Comment: Interesting - I tried, and if you use negative numbers, then `Min()` works. Not sure why not with positive.

Comment: Use it with the `IF()` function. Example: `=MIN(IF(B1:B7=B1,A1:A7))`

Comment: I believe the problem is that this function counts the value of cells corresponding to OTHER animals as zeroes, so it gives you the min, I am working on a solution and will come back but I thought for now this might help

Comment: sorry, my question was incomplete. I want to use it into a VBA code written on C col by using either `FormulaR1C1` or `FormulaArray`

Comment: @BruceWayne according to you, i tried with this weird formula `=-1/(MIN(INDEX(($B$1:$B$10=B1)*(-1)/($A$1:$A$10),0)))` and works!, but i dont understand it yet...

Answer (score 1):

I always use this for finding min and max with an array formula. Be sure to enter the below with a `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`.

```
{=MIN(IF($B$1:$B$7=B7,$A$1:$A$7,""))}
```

Comment: i have to use it for the whole range. By using `range("C1:C7").FormulaArray="=MIN(IF($B$1:$B$7=B7,$A$1:$A$7,""))"` doesn't work because of the cell B7. Any idea?

Comment: I gave you the formula based on your example. Change the range to match your needs.